# Protect routes with getInitialProps - Next.js

Tags: javascript, graphql, next.js

We're currently working on a user specific flow, that is needing some guards to prevent users visiting certain pages. We do this based on data coming from our GraphQL API, and as far as we know we should implement those guards inside the `getInitialProps`.

We would like to use some utility functions for this, instead of re-writing all the logic on every page. See here an example:

Snippet from our getInitialProps

```
Email.getInitialProps = async ({ req, res, apolloClient }) => {
  const deviceInfo = getDeviceInfo(req)

  try {
    const {
      data: { viewer },
    } = await apolloClient.query({
      query: GET_CHECKOUT,
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    })

    checkForCart(viewer, res)
    checkForProcessingPayment(viewer, res)

    return {
      namespacesRequired: ['buy-common', 'common', 'buy-email'],
      deviceInfo,
    }
  } catch (error) {
    const { href, as } = getLinkProps('CART')
    return redirect({ href, as }, res)
  }
}
```

The utility function (`handleRedirect` is just a redirect util that does a `res.redirect` and a `res.end` in the background)

```
export const checkForCart = ({ cart, checkout }, res) => {
  const { rows = [] } = checkout || {}

  if (!cart || !rows.length) {
    return handleRedirect('CART', res)
  }
}
```

This looks nice, because we just can use `checkForCart()` and not repeating this code for every page. It has one problem, and that is that the `return` of the `checkForCart` util is only returning the function, and not for the page. So, because the redirect takes some time, the code below the `checkForCart()` get's executed. So If I do a `console.log` below `checkForCart(viewer, res)` it will log.

Is there a neat way to stop execution form the util, or is there a neat way inside Next.js to fix cases like this? What is the best way to implement something like "guards"?

Comment: What about execute `checkForCart` and all the other logic  inside a   HOC component?

Comment: hey @NicolòCozzani thanks for your suggesting however we prevent using HOC's so it's not really an option for us, but the answer below helped us out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getInitialProps` is an `async` function which means you can take advantage of `await` syntax. Convert `checkForCart` into a function that returns a promise and `await` it, and then handle the result. For example:

```js
export const checkForCart = ({ cart, checkout }, res) => {
  const { rows = [] } = checkout || {}
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!cart || !rows.length) {
      reject()
    }
    resolve()
  })
}

Email.getInitialProps = async ({ req, res, apolloClient }) => {
  const deviceInfo = getDeviceInfo(req)

  try {
    const {
      data: { viewer },
    } = await apolloClient.query({
      query: GET_CHECKOUT,
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    })

    // If this rejects/fails because !cart || !rows.length
    // execution will jump to the catch block
    await checkForCart(viewer, res)

    // This won't run until checkForCart finishes and resolves
    checkForProcessingPayment(viewer, res)

    return {
      namespacesRequired: ['buy-common', 'common', 'buy-email'],
      deviceInfo,
    }
  } catch (error) {
    const { href, as } = getLinkProps('CART')
    return redirect({ href, as }, res)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! We used promises indeed, just in a different way. Instead of rejecting, we resolve if, `cart || rows.length` is true for example. Otherwise we just redirect without rejecting, because without resolve/reject the await will actually wait and so the user get's redirected.